# how to draw feynman diagram via TikZ-Feynman

Tags: diagrams, tikz-feynman, feynman

How can I draw this diagram through TikZ-Feynman.
thank you.
[image]

Comment: This one is literally on the cover page of the `tikz-feynman` manual.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code to produce the figure. The [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) of the `tikz-feynman` package gives many examples, and such figures are easy to produce with the help of this documentation, you should check it out!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{%
    i1 [particle=\(\bm{q}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2 [particle=\(\bar{\bm{q}}\)],
    a -- [gluon, edge label=\(\bm{g}\)] b,
    p1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] p2,
    p1 -- [photon, edge label'=\(\Gamma\)] p2,
    f1 [particle=\(\bar{\bm{t}}\)] -- [fermion] p1, 
    p2 -- [fermion] f2 [particle=\(\bm{t}\)],
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Next time, you should provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to show what you tried, and what did not work.

Comment: thanks for your kind help. appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, always glad to be helpful! :) And welcome to TeX.SX, by the way! To get used to the site, you could visit the help center, to see for example [how to ask a good question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) or [what to do when someone answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).